# When trying to run a jest test, I receive the error "sh: jest: command not found"

Tags: node.js, jestjs

Im working on a node command line application which requires jest testing.  Ive installed it as a dependency in my package.json, and when I try to run the 'npm run test' command, it gives me a bunch of errors.  Anyone know what's going on?  Im very new to node and web dev in general, so any feedback would be much appreciated!

[image: View the error message here]

Comment: Please, embed the image into the post, SO formatting allows that. The error means that Jest wasn't correctly installed, otherwise `jest` would be avaliable in npm script. Adding it to package.json is not enough. Make sure that `jest` really exists in package.json and reinstall modules, i.e. delete node_modules and run `npm i`.

Comment: Make sure `jest` is already installed.